# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:80) when attempting to test routes with TestServer

Tags: c#, routes, .net-6.0, mstest, asp.net-core-testhost

I'm attempting to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` to test routes via `TestServer`. I believe the `WebHost` setup I have should be sufficient; however, whenever I run my test, I receive an error message.

> Test method
> ID_Test.Controllers.Test_CloudPrintController_RouteTests.AppController_ShouldRouteCorrectly
> threw exception:  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
> (localhost:80) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

From my understanding, this is either related to firewall issues or incorrect `appsettings`; but if my `appsettings` work for all my other non-TestServer tests, and this uses the same `Program.cs` / `Startup.cs`, then I feel as if it should work for this as well.

Here is my test Class and the Mock Services I made.

```cs
public class MockAuthenticationService
{
    public async Task SignInAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Mock implementation of signing in
        // Contents removed for brevity
    }
}

public class MockAuthenticationSchemeProvider : IAuthenticationSchemeProvider
{
    // Contents removed for brevity
}

public class MockAuthenticationHandler : IAuthenticationHandler
{
    // Contents removed for brevity
}

public class MockAuthenticationHandlerProvider : IAuthenticationHandlerProvider
{
    // Contents removed for brevity
}

public class MockClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    // Contents removed for brevity
}

public class MockOptionsAuthentication : IOptions<AuthenticationOptions>
{
    // Contents removed for brevity
}

[TestClass]
public class Test_CloudPrintController_RouteTests : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            // Register mock implementations
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider, MockAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationHandlerProvider, MockAuthenticationHandlerProvider>();
            services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, MockClaimsTransformation>();
            services.AddSingleton<IOptions<AuthenticationOptions>, MockOptionsAuthentication>();
            services.AddSingleton<MockAuthenticationService>();

            // Register AuthenticationService with correct dependencies
            services.AddSingleton(sp =>
            {
                var mockAuthService = sp.GetRequiredService<MockAuthenticationService>();
                var mockSchemeProvider = sp.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
                var mockHandlers = sp.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationHandlerProvider>();
                var mockTransform = sp.GetRequiredService<IClaimsTransformation>();
                var mockOptions = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AuthenticationOptions>>();

                return new AuthenticationService(mockSchemeProvider, mockHandlers, mockTransform, mockOptions);
            });

            // Add JWT authentication for testing purposes
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // In test environment, set to false for simplicity
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false, // Set to false for testing
                    ValidateAudience = false, // Set to false for testing
                    ValidateLifetime = false, // Set to false for testing
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false, // Set to false for testing
                                                      // Modify other parameters as needed for testing purposes
                };
            });
        });
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [DoNotParallelize]
    public async Task AppController_ShouldRouteCorrectly()
    {
        // Arrange
        HttpClient _client = CreateClient();

        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        cookieContainer.Add(_client.BaseAddress, new Cookie("Cookie", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.MalKNawXYB0fdfe1644Ut_4rjb1W2QaBw236WVJrHTM"));
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
        _client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = _client.BaseAddress };

        // Simulate authentication by adding mock authentication token/header
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.MalKNawXYB0fdfe1644Ut_4rjb1W2QaBw236WVJrHTM");

        // Act
        var devResponse = await _client.GetAsync("/developer"); // 100 is the test printer node
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/subscription-bundles"); // 100 is the test printer node

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode); // This 404's, presumably cannot reach this endpoint through the test code
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Port 80 is an HTTP connection (unencrypted). Are you sure the server isn't expecting HTTPS traffic? That would be port 443. The exception message says that it connected, but the other machine hung up the phone. The network routes exist, but the server said "no way" to connecting over port 80.